# Pointer to a typedef with incomplete type

Tags: c++

Is there any way to declare a pointer to an incomplete type that will be set by a typedef in the implementation?

Here is exemple of what I want:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

namespace std {
    class string; // THIS WON'T WORK!
}

struct Test {
    std::string *value;
};

#endif
```

string is a typedef to basic_string, so the code in the exemple won't work. I could declare an incomplete type of std::basic_string, but thats looks like a workaround.

I know that the compiler won't generate symbols for typedefs, and it could happen that the same name could be used in typedefs for different types in different files. But since a pointer is a pointer (at least to the compiler), it should be possible to do something like that.

**EDIT**: This is just a minimalist working exemple. In my real problem, I have a Facade which uses a class from a library that only the Facade should need to know (no, it's not std::string, and the library is not stl). I'm not really worried with circular inclusion, but since a lot of files in my project include this Facade (directly or indirectly), I am worried with compile time, so I want to include the library file only in the Facade's implementation file.

Comment: Many compilers provide a `<stringfwd>` which provides a working forward declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not.

Really, at this point, you're just going to have to `#include <string>`. It's not harmful because you can't have a circular dependency with `string`: standard headers don't even know that your headers exist!

A `std::string*` is usually wrong, anyway.

Comment: I agree that std::string* is usually wrong, but that was just a minimalist working example.

Comment: It should also makes sense, otherwise it doesn't really exhibit anything. Anyway...

Comment: Ok, I edited my question adding more information about the real problem.

Answer (score 3):

Forward declaring `std::string` might look something like this:

```
namespace std
{
    template <class T, class Traits, class Allocator>
    class basic_string;

    template <class T>
    class char_traits;

    template <class T>
    class allocator;

    typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > string;
}
```

[Example.](http://ideone.com/NEwsL)

(This doesn't attempt to forward declare that `basic_string` has default template arguments. Since those can only be declared once, I suspect only library authors might have enough control to pull it off.)

---

As to questioning the usage of `std::string*`, I guess no-one would allocate them dynamically. However, isn't it valid to want to reference some other string elsewhere (or NULL)?

Answer (score 1):

Declaring stuff in `namespace std` is (mostly) undefined. The only legal way to refer to a standard library object, function or type is after including a relevant header. 17.4.3.1 says so.